# How can you 'reuse' a git branch safely

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-merge, git-reset

I need to way to update a Git branch to a new ref in such a way that from the client's view a new branch. I have a process in mind but I want advice on edge cases I haven't accounted for.

Use case here is we develop in master and want to code freeze at regular intervals and update the release branch to where master is at the point. We don't want to create a new branch each time because our automation would need to be updated to use the new branch.

Through process we're limited who and how commits can happen to release, (cherry-picks from master only in the end), so there shouldn't be commits in release that aren't in master. Process is never perfect though so I want to guard a little.

Right now I'm planning on using 'reset --hard' via this:

```
git checkout master
MASTER_HEAD=`git rev-parse HEAD`
git checkout release
git reset --hard $MASTER_HEAD
git push -f origin
```

This is a little scary because if a commit does get into release thats not in master its possible for it to make it into release on the next pull someone does. Any forced push freaks me out as well.

I've also looked at 'update-ref' but I don't understand it yet.

The last method is once a release is cut, tag the release branch and delete the branch. Then when code freeze happens again recreate release from master. Downside here is any automation also needs to be disable as the branch doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I can't quite tell but it seems like you are going through a lot of pain and anguish for no reason. Forgive my assumptions, but it seems like an `enhancement` to your automation to allow it to change to a new release branch would be trivial. IMHO the best way for you to get what you want is to work on `master` branch a `release` off that. Make your release fixes in `release` and merge the relevant ones back to `master`. Once your happy with `release` tag it, stop working on that branch, and create a new branch for the next release.

Comment: There's a good bit of legacy automation that's not the easiest to update right now. That's the push behind keeping a single branch name. Our current git structure is also causing problems so this has priority over updating all the automation. But otherwise yes, that would be the way I'd want do it given the time.

Comment: If you are truly stuck then you're stuck, but I would be cautious with the word `safe`. Remember the unix design philosophy is strong with git. Especially the part where it `doesn't stop you from doing stupid things because that would stop you from doing clever things`. You can muck with the `refs` that compose a `branch` object but you'll have to use your judgement as to whether what you are doing is `stupid` or `clever`

Answer (score 0):

The approach to update the remote branch seems correct.

One caveat is that if a new commit is pushed to `release` that is not a a fast-follow commit from previous `release`s, there could be a undesirable merge if someone where to update they local `release` branch through the usual `git pull`.

Any updates to local `release` branches should be done through:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/release
```

Comment: That is exactly the crux of my problem. There are a number of commits that we don't want to pulled in as well and I don't trust this to happen every time. A git hook could protect against it but it'd be expensive and we could never turn it off because someone could use a old computer a year or two from now and not remember to do this when doing a pull.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved in a simpler fashion by merging master into release. I don't see why that would be a problem, let us know if there's a good reason. I'd do the following:

```
git checkout rebase
git merge master
git push -f origin
```

Comment: That would be awesome, but is not possible for reasons I never want to speak of and were not in my control.